# yum epel depsolving problems when installing R

Tags: yum, rhel-5

I am trying to install R on an old RHEL5 system. `sudo yum install R` reveals

```
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package R.x86_64 0:2.15.2-1.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libRmath-devel = 2.15.2-1.el5 for package: R
--> Processing Dependency: R-devel = 2.15.2-1.el5 for package: R
--> Running transaction check
---> Package R-devel.x86_64 0:2.15.2-1.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: R-core = 2.15.2-1.el5 for package: R-devel
--> Processing Dependency: pcre-devel for package: R-devel
---> Package libRmath-devel.i386 0:2.15.2-1.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libRmath = 2.15.2-1.el5 for package: libRmath-devel
--> Running transaction check
---> Package R-core.x86_64 0:2.15.2-1.el5 set to be updated
---> Package libRmath-devel.i386 0:2.15.2-1.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libRmath = 2.15.2-1.el5 for package: libRmath-devel
---> Package pcre-devel.x86_64 0:6.6-6.el5_6.1 set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
libRmath-devel-2.15.2-1.el5.i386 from epel has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libRmath = 2.15.2-1.el5 is needed by package libRmath-devel-2.15.2-1.el5.i386 (epel)
Error: Missing Dependency: libRmath = 2.15.2-1.el5 is needed by package libRmath-devel-2.15.2-1.el5.i386 (epel)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Not sure what the issue is here. `sudo yum install libRmath` tells me

```
Package matching libRmath-2.15.2-1.el5.x86_64 already installed. Checking for update.
Nothing to do
```

Here is my repolist:

```
repo id                                                                                          repo name                                                                                                          status
epel                                                                                             Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - x86_64                                                                      7,407
rhel-x86_64-client-5                                                                             Red Hat Enterprise Linux Desktop (v. 5 for 64-bit x86_64)                                                          11,070
rhel-x86_64-client-supplementary-5                                                               RHEL Desktop Supplementary (v. 5 for 64-bit x86_64)                                                                 1,559
rhel-x86_64-client-supplementary-5-debuginfo                                                     RHEL Desktop Supplementary Debuginfo (v. 5 for 64-bit x86_64)                                                           9
rhel-x86_64-client-workstation-5                                                                 RHEL Desktop Workstation (v. 5 for 64-bit x86_64)                                                                   6,379
rhel-x86_64-client-workstation-5-debuginfo                                                       RHEL Desktop Workstation Debuginfo (v. 5 for 64-bit x86_64)                                                         3,565
rhn-tools-rhel-x86_64-client-5                                                                   Red Hat Network Tools for RHEL Client (v.5 64-bit x86_64)                                                             533
```

Comment: libRmath-devel-2.15.2-1.el5."i386" , libRmath-2.15.2-1.el5."x86_64" are different.

Comment: Why would it be looking for "i386" version. Isnt that 32 bit?

Comment: i386 means 32bit and x86_64 means 64bit.